# What is wrong with Django csv upload code?

Tags: django, csv

Here is my code. I would like to import csv and save it to database via model.

```
class DataInput(forms.Form):
        file = forms.FileField(label="Select CSV file")

        def save(self, mdl):
            records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data["file"].read().decode('utf-8'), delimiter=',')
            if mdl=='auction':
                auction = Auction()
                for line in records:
                    auction.auction_name = line[0]
                    auction.auction_full_name = line[1]
                    auction.auction_url = line[2]
                    auction.is_group = line[3]
                    auction.save()
```

Now, it throws the following error.

```
Exception Type:     IndexError
Exception Value:    list index out of range
```

csv file

```
RTS,Rapid Trans System,www.rts.com,TRUE
ZAA,Zelon Advanced Auton,www.zaa.info,FALSE
```

Really stuck. Please, help.

Comment: Tip: what if there are missing columns?

Comment: I think problem is in read().decode('utf-8'). now I am thinking to decode it without reading with read()

Comment: Not related to the issue in question, but unless you only want to save an auction for the final line, you should move the `auction` variable definition into the for-loop.

Comment: you need to create the auction object inside the loop if you want separate objects to be created.

Comment: thx. before my objects was inside. I intentionally take it outside. Even I put inside it does not work. When I run print (row) it gives ['R']
['T']
['S']
['', '']

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the full stacktrace should reveal exactly where the error is.  Give Django the `--traceback` argument, e.g. `./manage.py --traceback runserver`.

As Burhan Khalid mentioned 10 minutes ago you miss the 5th column in your csv file (index 4), so that is the root of the error.

Comment: and what does the stacktrace say?  Is the CSV by any change terminated by a line-break?

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the file with `.read()`, you are passing in the complete string - which is why each row is an individual character.

You need to pass the entire file object, without reading it first:

```
records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data["file"], delimiter=',')
```

If you need to decode it first, then you had better run through the file yourself:

```
for line in self.cleaned_data['file'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
    if line.strip():
        try:
            name, full_name, url, group = line.split(',')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid line: {}'.format(line))
            continue
        i = Auction()
        i.auction_name = name
        i.action_full_name = full_name
        i.auction_url = url
        i.is_group = group
        i.save()
```

Comment: Thx, it was like before. But it throws error because it cannot decode it. I should somehow decode it, else it always throws an error.